# How do I write a test class for invocable variable

Tags: unit-test, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have an invocable method with variables. I am stuck how to set these in unittest.

```
public class getBWS {  
    @InvocableMethod(label='Status' description='') 
    public static List<FlowOutputs>invokeThisMethod(List<FlowInputs>request){
        List<FlowOutputs> result = new List<FlowOutputs>();
            FlowOutputs output = new FlowOutputs();
            AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT sum(BWS1_val) BWS1, sum(BWS2_val) BWS2 FROM CustomCC__c WHERE Status__c = :request[0].Status]; 
            for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
                output.BWS1     = (double)ar.get('BWS1');
                output.BWS2     = (double)ar.get('BWS2');
                result.add(output);
            }
        return result;                   
    }
    
    // input details which comes from flow to apex
    public class FlowInputs{
        @InvocableVariable
        public string Status;
    }
    
    // output details which goes from apex to flow
    public class FlowOutputs{
        @InvocableVariable
        public double BWS1;       
        @InvocableVariable
        public double BWS2;
    }
}
```

**TESTCLASS**

```
@isTest
private class getBWS_Test {
    
    static testMethod void testMethod1() {
                    
        String Status = 'B';
                    
        CustomCC__c cc = new CustomCC__c (
            BWS1_val__c = 500,
            BWS2_val__c = 100,
            Status__c   = 'B',
        );
        insert cc;
        
        getBWS .invokeThisMethod(new List<getBWS .FlowInputs>{Status});

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the flow input parameters from the test class as below.

```
getBWS.FlowInputs fi = new getBWS.FlowInputs();
fi.Status= cc.Status__c;

getBWS.invokeThisMethod(new List<getBWS.FlowInputs>{fi});
```

Comment: I change my code as you mentioned, but I still get an error Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: List<getBWS.FlowInputs> but was: getBWS.FlowInputs

Comment: there was small correction and I have updated it now